# Access external files

Tags: java, eclipse

Am using nio2 to read the external file in my desktop using eclipse. I am getting the exception for the following code.

"`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException`: `C:\Users\User\Desktop\JEE\FirstFolder\first.txt`"

Kindly advise how to resolve it? Tried using command prompt also. Getting the same exception.

```
public class ReadingExternalFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path p1= Paths.get("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\FirstFolder\\first.txt");
        System.out.println(p1.toString());
        System.out.println(p1.getRoot());

        try(InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(p1);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)))
            {
            System.out.println("Inside try");
            String line=null;           
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                if (!line.equals("")) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    }
                //System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println( e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why you are using a Path object, you can simply make the file using the File object and just using the string as the path, and then wraping it in a file reader object then wrapping that in a buffered reader, the end should look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\FirstFolder\\first.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fr);

        System.out.println(bfr.readLine());

        bfr.close();

    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

don't forget to close your streams after reading and writing, also use readable names (don't do what I've done, use meaningful names!)

Comment: Hi Thank you for the info.I am aware of this way,I was trying to learn nio2 and got the error while using "Paths" class.Can you suggest how to use nio2 to read files in this case  ?

Comment: it would be nice if you could add the console output, including the errors at the bottom of your question and explicitly say in your question that you want to use the nio2 package.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope this will help you.

```
    Path p1= Paths.get("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\FirstFolder\\first.txt");


try(
    BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(p1, Charset.defaultCharset()))
    {
    System.out.println("Inside try");
    String line=null;           
    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
        if (!line.equals("")) {
            System.out.println(line);
            }
        //System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println( e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\FirstFolder\\first.txt"));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.I am familiar with this way .Can you tell me how to read using Paths classes  ??.I am trying to learn nio2 and got this error while trying.

Comment: Which version of java did you used here??
java 8??

Comment: Nope am using java 7.

Comment: Did you put proper path **"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\FirstFolder\\first.txt"** ??
i see your code is fine and run well.before run, please clean and build the project.

Comment: Tried clean the project .But still getting the same error. Run the program using command prompt also go the same error.Are you able to run the code and get the output ??. Thank you .

Comment: yes. i run your code and getting output on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\FirstFolder\\first.txt");
    FileReader freader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufreader = new BufferedReader(freader);

    System.out.println(bufreader.readLine());

    bufreader.close();

} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Thank you for the info.I am aware of this way,I was trying to learn nio2 and got the error while using "Paths" class.Can you suggest how to use nio2 to read files in this case ?